# Bulk regenerate slugs

Tags: slug, entry-slug

I’ve already got a ton of content put in by the client, and there’s quite a bit of accented characters (é, à, ...) in the titles, and thus also in the slugs where they get url encoded, which my client considers 'ugly'.

Now I’ve added the `limitAutoSlugsToAscii' => true` rule to the config, but how can I best rework the url’s for the already existing content? There’s about 1000 entries already in the website so I’d rather not go over them by hand.

Can I just clear the slug column in the database? Or will I have to write a temporary custom controller action that I can trigger to loop over all entries to redo their slug? Or is there another (better) solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or will I have to write a temporary custom controller action that I can trigger to loop over all entries to redo their slug?

This one.

The plugin could then just use `StringHelper::asciiString($slug);` to do the ASCII conversion and re-save it back to the database.